# seg fault: Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ALPHABET_LENGTH    26
#define OPERATION_BUF_SIZE  5
#define NAME_BUF_SIZE      22
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE       27

#ifndef NULL 
#define NULL ((void*)0) 
#endif

/* Basic trie node -- also, keep track of number of nodes below this one. */
typedef struct node {
    int num_children;
    struct node *children[ALPHABET_LENGTH];
} trie_node;

trie_node* init(trie_node* a) {
    a->num_children = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        a->children[i] = NULL;
    }
    return a;
}

char* trim(char* a){
    if (a[0] == 'a')
    {
        a += 4;
    }else{
        a += 5;
    }
    return a;
}

void add(char* a, trie_node* node){//need to make sure a is not NULL at beginning
    trie_node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode = init(newNode);
    int i;
    if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] == NULL)
    {
        node->num_children++;
        //initialize the children array
        for (i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            if (newNode->children[i] != NULL)
            {
                newNode->children[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
        newNode -> num_children = 0;
        node->children[a[0] - 97] = newNode;
        a++;
        add(a, newNode);
    }
    else if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] != NULL){
        a++;
        node->num_children++;
        add(a, node->children[a[0] - 97]);
    } else{//a == NULL, which means end of the add procedure
        return;
    }
    free(newNode);
}

int main()
{
    int t,total,remain,temp;
    scanf("%d\n", &t);
    total = t;
    trie_node* contacts = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    contacts = init(contacts);
    while(t != 0){
        char* s = malloc(MAX_BUF_SIZE); //char array to store the input
        t--;
        remain = total - t;
        fgets(s, MAX_BUF_SIZE, stdin);
        if (s[0] == 'a')
        {
            s = trim(s);
            //do add operation
            if (s != NULL)
            {//make sure there is something to add
                add(s, contacts);
            }

        }
        else{
            printf("No such operation found at line %d. (Only add or find is allowed)\n", remain);
        }
        free(contacts);
        free(s);//memory leak problem
    }

    //if operation is not add or find, will be an error.
    return 0;
}
```

Every time my program goes into the second case in add function, which is the else if statement, it will segfault saying that node->children[a[0]-97] can not be accessed.
For example, I do add abc and then add acd. This will get a segfault.
Also, I believe there is some memory leak in my function. I check my code in valgrind. It says invalid free() at free(s) 
Sorry, I should mention this at beginning. a assume to be consisted of lower case letters. And all my test input for now, only consider add and find operations.

Comment: `s = trim(s);` will do strange things if strlen(a) happens to be <=4.

Comment: `if (s != NULL)`  should be checked before `fgets(s, MAX_BUF_SIZE, stdin);`

Comment: BTW each time you create a `newNode` and then you'll free at at the end of add function, so second time that memory does not exists.....

Comment: `malloc()` returns void pointer, typecast it to the required type.

Comment: Seriously: time to learn how to debug....

Comment: It can not be `free(s);` after `s = trim(s);`. because it differs from `malloc`'s return value.

Comment: Check `islower(a[0])`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So in this case, if the value changed, do I still need to free s? If I do, how to free it?

Comment: @LPs Thanks for the reply! I tried not free newNode before. The problem is still here. I still cannot access the newNode at second case in the loop

Comment: `free` must be applied. For example, you can do as follows. `char* buff = malloc(MAX_BUF_SIZE);while(t != 0){
        char* s = buff;... } free(buff);` or `char buff[MAX_BUF_SIZE];` instead of `char* buff = malloc(MAX_BUF_SIZE);` Alos `free(contacts);` move to after while-loop.and Let's free the entire tree.

Comment: @MilindDeore [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1848654).

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fgets()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both).  variable names like `t`, `s`, `a`  are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the `init()` function is returned exactly what was passed to it.  I.E. a point to an instance of the `struct node`.  None of the posted code actually needs the `init()` function to return anything,  Suggest this line: `contacts - init( contacts);` be replaced with `init( contacts );` and the `init()` function be modified accordingly.

Comment: in the `add()` function, the parameter name is `node`, which is the same as the `struct node` definition`   This is a poor programming practice.  Modern C compilers can handle it as the names are kept in separate name spaces, but it is confusing to the reader.

Comment: the `add()` function is excessively recursive.  Amongst other things the `if else` block is not handling the results of the call to `malloc()`, so that pointer is lost.  This is a memory leak

Comment: in the `trim()` function, the pointer `a` is being incremented by 4 or 5 (not really a 'trim' operation)  There is nothing in the code to indicate what that 4 or 5 is actually accomplishing.  Infact, there is nothing in the code to indicate the expected format of the data line entered by the user.

Comment: there are a LOT of calls to `malloc()`, and (per the code) will need a loop to free() all the allocated memory segments, BUT there is no loop that calls `free()`

Comment: this line: `printf("No such operation found at line %d. (Only add or find is allowed)\n", remain);` indicates a `add` or a `find` operation are allowed, but there is no code for the `find` operation

Comment: nothing in the posted code is making use of the contents of the `string.h` nor the `math.h` header files.  It is a poor programming practice to `#include` header files those contents are not being used.

Comment: the variable `remain` is actually the current line number, read from the user, and not the `remain`der of anything.  Suggest using a meaningful variable name

Comment: this comment: `//if operation is not add or find, will be an error.` is related to the `else` code block in `main()`, not to the exiting of the program,  Please correct this oversight.

Comment: in `main()`, at the bottom of the `while()` loop, the code passes the pointer `contacts` to `free()` but during the next pass through the loop, uses that pointer as if it were still valid. This is a logic error and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: @MilindDeore,  a `void*` can be assigned to any other pointer.  It only needs to be typecast in C++ and this is NOT C++.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: this expression: `node->children[a[0] - 97] == NULL)` and this expression: `node->children[a[0] - 97] = newNode;`  make the assumption that `a[0]` is a lower case letter,  What happens if it is uppercase?  What happens if it is a space?  What happens if it is punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for all of you who reply my question. The real problem in my function is I modified a before I access the node position using a[0].

Here is how I fix the problem:

```
void add(char* a, trie_node* node){//need to make sure a is not NULL at beginning
    int i,temp;
    if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] == NULL)
    {
        node->num_children++;
        //initialize the children array
        trie_node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newNode = init(newNode);
        node->children[a[0] - 97] = newNode;
        a++;
        add(a, newNode);
    }
    else if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] != NULL){
        node->num_children++;
        temp = a[0];
        a++;
        add(a, node->children[temp - 97]);//line 56
    } else{//a == NULL, which means end of the add procedure
        return;
    }
}
```

I add a int temp to store the value of a[0], and then do a++. 
Before I do this, if I "add abc" then "add acd", in the second loop, at line 56, add function will get value of a as "cd\n", and value of node->children[a[0]-97] where a[0] is c now instead of a. 
Now everything is fixed. Thanks all!

Comment: still the problem, what if `a[0]` is not a ascii lower case letter?

Comment: the char pointer `a` will NEVER be NULL until `a` is incremented until it loops back to 0!  I suspect your looking for the NUL string termination byte so you should use: `(*a != '\0')` or `(a[0] != '\0')`  or `(*a)`.

Comment: @user3629249 this is not an real application. So as question mentioned, a must be consisted of lower case letters. Thanks for pointing out that